# Array not saving from one model to another in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I am trying to save an array of multiple ids (item_variation_ids) to a model called items_stock from item variations model. In a column called item_variation_ids in item_stock, it is saving the ids like [1,2,3] for twice. I want the item_variation_ids to be saved once only with 1,2,3 in a single column.
My item_variation model

```
#app/models/item_variation
class ItemVariation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  validates_associated :item
  after_save :add_to_item_stock

 def add_to_item_stock
   ItemStock.create(item_variation_ids: ItemVariation.ids, items_id: items_id)
 end
end
```

My item model

```
 #app/models/item
 class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_variations, foreign_key: :items_id
  has_many :item_stocks, foreign_key: :items_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_stocks
end
```

My item_stock model

```
#app/models/item_stock
class ItemStock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Comment: You are creating an ItemStock with ALL ItemVariation ids whenever you save any ItemVariation. Also, what does ItemStock look like? show your 3 models, where does `items_id` come from? did you mean `item_id`? You should explain your problem a little better and share all the related code. An example of what you have on the DB before and after the problem would be even better.

Comment: I have added another two models please check

Comment: I'm not sure what's inside ItemStock. You are trying to save a `item_variations_ids` and an `items_id` but I only see an association that would be `item_id`. Can you explain a real life example what is each model? I guess you are using the wrong associations but I'm not sure.

Comment: @arieljuod real example is here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350010/how-to-insert-comma-separated-values-in-rails-active-admin-form

Comment: Hmmm that's not a real example, it's like your question but with an activeadmin config and a picture. You should really answer al lthe question anyone asks on a comment. Where does `items_id` come from on the after_save callback, are you aware that ItemVariation.ids returns ALL ids on the database and you are trying to create an ItemStock with ALL ids each time? I still don't understand what you are trying to do and I don't understand the use of ItemStock since it only has a belongs_to item, no idea what's your database schema to make sense to that item_variations_ids (why not a has_many?)

Comment: I need to store the stock quantity of each variation combination so that has_many doesn't work. E.g i just need item_variation_ids=1,2,3 , stock_qty=20 in item_stock table where I don't want ItemVariation.ids returns ALL ids . I hope you understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But how do you know which ItemVariation ids should go on that ItemStock? and you are creating one ItemStock each time any variation gets saved. I don't even think you need to set that ids array since the ItemStock already belongs to an Item which has many variations (@item_stock.item.variations and you are done).

Also now you are talking about a `stock_qty` attribute you never mentioned before, you are never setting it on the callback and you didn't show your database schema. where does that amout come from? is an attribute on the variation that you want to sum to the current item_stock?

I also don't understand why an item has many item stocks for the code you are showing.

I'll do a wild guess and suggest you do something like:

```
ItemStock
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :item_variation
end

ItemVariation
  after_save :add_to_item_stock

  def add_to_item_stock
    item_stock = self.item.item_stock.where(item_variation_id: self.id).first_or_initialize
    item_stock.stock_qty = self.stock_qty
    item_stock.save
  end
end
```

but as I said, it's a wiiiiild guess. I'd recommend you to first try to understand what you are doing, because it seems like you just copied to code from that question you linked and you are no actually understanding it.